# User-Defined Type Guard Results in Intersection Type

Tags: typescript

I'm playing around with Typescript and was trying to see if I could create the concept of an `Either` type to represent success and failure paths. I've created a user-defined type guard to explicitly narrow the types of success/failure through the use of a Symbol. I can't figure out why the value of `either` in the isFailure branch is shown as being the intersection type of `Data & CustomError` as opposed to just `CustomError`.

```
const FailureSymbol = Symbol('Failure');

interface IFailure {
    symbol: Symbol;
}

type Success<T> = T
type Failure<T extends IFailure> = T

type Either<T, U extends IFailure> = Success<T> | Failure<U>

function isFailure<T, U extends IFailure>(either: Either<T, U>): either is Failure<U> {
    const candidateFailure = either as Failure<U>;
    return candidateFailure.symbol && candidateFailure.symbol === FailureSymbol;
}

interface Data {
    data: string;
}

interface CustomFailure {
    symbol: Symbol;
    errorMessage: string;
}

let either: Either<Data, CustomFailure> = { data: 'success' }; 

if (isFailure<Data, CustomFailure>(either)) {
    // inside this branch the type of either is shown to be: Data & CustomFailure
    console.log('failure', either);
} else {
    // inside this branch the type of either is show to be: Data
    console.log('success', either)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why the value of either in the isFailure branch is shown as being the
>   intersection type of Data & CustomError as opposed to just CustomError

because `isFailure` check follows immediately after `either` was initialized with a value that has `Data` type. The compiler infers types and uses control flow analysis when appropriate, so in this case it remembers that `either` value has `Data` type. You can see it if you try to assign `either` to something declared as `Data`, you get no error:

```
const either2: Data = either; //no error, either has `Data` type here
```

When `either` type is not narrowed, it works as expected. Control flow analysis stops at function boundaries, so if you have the same code inside the function it will be inferred as `CustsomFailure` only:

```
function test(either: Either<Data, CustomFailure>) {
  if (isFailure<Data, CustomFailure>(either)) {
      // here either is CustomFailure
      console.log('failure', either);
  } else {
      // inside this branch the type of either is show to be: Data
      console.log('success', either)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I still keep getting surprised by how smart the TS compiler is and how well they've developed control flow analysis. Seeing it with the test function in your example where the types matched what I originally suspected helped make it clear